# Unable to retrieve EditText value using findViewById

Tags: android

I am developing a very basic Android Application, issue is when I am trying to retrieve the value of `EditText` widget it’s giving me empty a string.

my code is as Follows:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button generateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    generateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //generateFibonacci();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            EditText seedValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            TextView fibonacciSeries = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            String a = seedValue.getText().toString();
            try {
                int seedNumber = Integer.parseInt(seedValue.getText().toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    seedNumber += seedNumber;
                    fibonacciSeries.append(Integer.toString(seedNumber));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                fibonacciSeries.append(e.toString());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

and in activity.xml

```
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:ems="10" />
```

The other similar looking questions here on SO are usually getting solved by correcting the layout, but I think I am already in the correct layout as my controls are in the same layout which is the one I am initializing i.e. `R.layout.activity_main`
kindly help.

Comment: Is there two xmls named `activity.xml` and `activity_main.xml` ?

Comment: activity.xml or activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` twice. You should not call that in `onClick()` again.

Also try declaring `EditText seedValue` as instance variable in your Activity class.

```
public YourActivity extends Activity {
    EditText seedValue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button generateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        generateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            seedValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            ...
            ...
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: oh damn! Thankyou it got solved by removing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` from the onClick method. Thankyou so much.